# Sitecore Content Hub Localization

Tags: multilingual, content-hub

Is there any 3rd party module/connector available to automate the translation process in Content Hub?

I know we can do this manually from translation page where we can enter translations manually and Content Hub also provides a method to export content for translation in Microsoft Excel format where external translator or translation agency performs the translation. But the ask is for automate translation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options to use here. Depends on how far you want to develop your own solution or leverage existing integrations.

- [GPI plugin](https://www.translationplugin.com/index.php/sitecore-content-hub-translation/)
- [Smartling](https://www.smartling.com/)
- [XTM](https://xtm.cloud/)
- [Languagewire](https://www.languagewire.com/en)
- [Wordbee](https://wordbee.com/)

Let us know how you get on.

Answer (score 0):

With the recent addition of Microsoft Open AI into the mix, it is a viable option that you can use with Sitecore Connect. This requires no code to be developed and it is faster than developing or integrating with something on your own.

This may have cost implications depending on whether you have them already or need to purchase it new.